# error with int* to int conversion , with no integer and just two pointers

Tags: c++11, pointers

I get a int to int* conversion error for the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int *a,b;
    a=b;
}
```

and I do not get any error for the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    a=b;
}
```

I don't the difference these two cases have.
Can I not declare pointers together?

Comment: yes, yes. I should've declared *a,*b to get to pointers

Comment: If you want to declare two pointer objects, write `int *a, *b;` -- or better yet write two separate declarations as in your second snippet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It depends on what?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I wouldn't call anything other than `int *a; int *b;` on two separate lines "nifty". What do you have in mind? (I sometimes enjoy writing obfuscated code, but I'm under no illusion that it's actually *good*.)

Comment: @KeithThompson What I had in mind seems silly after having had a good nights sleep and I'd like to forget all about it. Apologies to everyone having read my confusing comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet of code declares a pointer and an int. The snippets are not equivalent.